# JavaScript window.onbeforeunload not firing every time

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am working a project. In the head section I have the following code in my head section so that the console is cleared every time I refresh the page.

Code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    console.clear();
};
```

The point of this is to make sure all errors, warnings, or messages are deleted (Safari doesn't delete console errors/warnings/messages when the page is refreshed.)

This should work, and it does, but it does not fire every time. Most of the time it does but about one out of ten times it doesn't.

Does anyone know why it is not firing every time?

Thank you.

Note: I could use `window.addEventListener()` instead of `window.onbeforeunload` but I chose not to.

Comment: Take that out and get a better browser; both Firefox and Chrome clear the console upon navigation by default.

Comment: @minitech I am aware of that. I have both of those browsers on my mac but I would like to try to make Safari do it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari `onbeforeunload` is a bit buggy. Safari developers are working on fixing it, but for now, I would use a different browser.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Nobel Chicken.